# Do keywords affect Bluemix Watson speech recognition?

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Watson's speech recognizer supports a list of keywords as a parameter, but I'm trying to figure out whether these keywords actually *affect recognition*. For example, if you were handing Watson an audio clip you knew to contain proper names that might not be properly recognized, would submitting these names as keywords increase the likelihood that Watson would properly recognize them? Do the keywords interact with the recognition itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately the answer is no, the words wont get added to the vocabulary just because you added them as keywords, so they wont be found.

Dani

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer to this is no (though I'd love to be proven wrong here): I ran a test clip that contained proper names that Watson mis-recognized, then submitted the same clip with those names as keywords, and it didn't change the transcript at all.

Not entirely conclusive, but it seems like the answer is no.